# show a list of the pages you manage toggle is off by default

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

My app has been approved for pages_show_list and permissions listed below. Everything was working fine till yesterday, but suddenly when user tries to login, **show a list of the pages you manage** toggle is off by default.

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8,9)'
Permissions used : "email, public_profile, pages_show_list, business_management"

Login page image

[image]

Comment: There is no way for you to specify this behavior, this is up to Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe This happens only for Android devices.

Comment: Kindly check the screenshot. https://ibb.co/F5nWpYW. In some apps, when we login using a web browser in android or an android app, the **show the list of pages** toggle is on by default and it's disabled. Do you know any workaround to implement the same?

Comment: There is no way for you to specify the behavior, all you can do is ask for the permission. What UI Facebook actually presents to ask the user for those permissions, is up to them.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for looking into our issue. We have found a solution. Adding a permission which is dependent on 'pages_show_list' will make the toggle on and make it disabled. For eg. pages_read_enagagement.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a permission which is dependent on 'pages_show_list' will make the toggle on and make it disabled. For eg. pages_read_enagagement (but needs to be requested for approval).

Refer permission dependencies [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview/permissions-features/).